# Inserting MYSQL string into an image source for displaying purposes

Tags: php, mysql, post

I know I am doing something very simple that's wrong...I just can't figure it out. Any    suggestions?

```
<img src='photos/<?php echo $row['filename'];?>/'>;
```

Im looking for  to be inserted to look like
    `<img src="photos/$row['filename']">` < but that is not the proper format.

Comment: How do you know you're doing something wrong? The image doesn't show up? Browser throws an error? You have to be specific.

Comment: @esqew yea the image doesnt show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When outputing your string inside a php file use following code

```
echo '<img src="photos/' . $row['filename'] . '">';
```

For better readability you could use printf:

```
printf('<img src="photos/%s">', $row['filename']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the trailing slash from your declaration.

```
<img src='photos/<?php echo $row['filename'];?>'>
```

Most servers won't respond in the way you expect when you add a trailing slash (`/`) to the filename of a resource. Picky, but technically wrong, because a file is not a directory (referencing a directory in certain environments requires the trailing slash).

When evaluated, your expression will come out to something akin to

```
<img src='photos/img001.jpg/'>
```

when in reality, that resource is actually at

```
<img src='photos/img001.jpg'>
```

Comment: hmmm how do i echo it thp

Comment: @Lauer What? I have the modified version of your example in my post.

Comment: echo  '   <img src='photos/<?php echo $row['filename'];?>'>'; Im confusing myself...is this propper?

Comment: For even better code you could use the [echo shortcut syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). `<img src="photos/"<?= $row['filename']; ?>">`

Comment: @Lauer is your code inside a html file (so called view) or in a php file?

Comment: @Lauer right click the page, and click "view source" you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in <b>/srv/disk4/1689402/www/lifeatbagram.atwebpages.com/free.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br /> @Loïc

Comment: @Otanaught it's inside a php file, im just trying to echo that variable and for some reasons its not working

Comment: @Lauer You need to check your quotes (and learn how to debug your code)! You also should have mentioned that you're using `echo` to output this, as it is a slightly different solution: `echo '<img src="photos/' . echo $row['filename'] . '">';`

Comment: @Lauer You dont need to echo your result twice, ill create a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see a trailing slash at the end of the img tag. It may cause this problem.

Comment: i took it out... im having trouble mostly displaying it without having en error...

Answer (score 0):

The easies way that can make you avoid `""` and `''` problems is to make html string on echo :

```
echo "<img src='photos/" . $row['filename'] . "' />";
```

Comment: you're welcome ! a positive vote or  specifying my answer as correct would be nice ! @Lauer